# Why won't my BufferedImage show in the .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, jlabel, bufferedimage

Alright, so I have created a Buffered Image to display on a JLabel. When I display the File location, it requires a src/ in front of the folder I want to access, or else an error will arise and I will not see the Buffered Image... I know that if I put the 'src/' in front of the resImg, the BufferedImage will not display outside of the IDE. Can anyone help?
This is the code that works inside of the IDE. When running outside from the .jar file, the image doesn't display.

```
static File f = new File("src/resImg/banner.png");

try {
        banner = ImageIO.read(f);
        picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(banner));
        LabelPanel.add(picLabel);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GameStart.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: You can only refer to a `File` which is on the filesystem. For those in a jar you should treat them as a resource.

Answer (score 2):

When the resource is in a jar file, it isn't a file on the local file system. You should use

```
URL imageSource = getClass().getResource("/resImg/banner.png");
if (imageSource == null) {
    // Handle the resource being missing
}
picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageSource));
```

Here you're fetching the resources from the classloader, which will obviously have access to the files in your jar file.

Comment: What if I am in a static method? How would I proceed? It is saying that getClass() is a non-static method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want get image from jar, use smth like this:

```
URL imageurl = getClass().getResource("/images/imagename");
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a `File` object for a resource in the JAR file. Use this instead.

```
URL imgurl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resImg/banner.png");
picLabel - new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgurl));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find a parent directory, the relativ path can start from like

- workspace directory
- directory the process starts

the relativ path is "realtiv" from where the java process is started from, so the path can change from time to time.

If the picture is placed in the jar, you can use

```
getClass().getResource("relativ jar path")
```

for finding the image. the jar itself knows, where it is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is that your image is not packed inside jar file ( verify this with jar / zip tool ).

If image is there but does not display, it is because you trying to read this from file system relative to working directory ( and it is certainly not there )

So, proper solution would be  to read image from class path:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassloader().getResourceAsStream(... path to your image relative to jar root ---)
```